# iOS Development, Objective-c Development, Сложная проблема, Swift ошибка

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone, cocoapods

У меня есть большая проблема, которую не могу решить, пожалуйста, помогите. Вот и сама проблема - https://prnt.sc/26tm3rp. Сложность в том, что я пробовал pod deintegrate -> pod init -> pod install, cmd+shift+k, clear derived data, также нашел видео на ютубе - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1OY9WKfQbQ&ab_channel =FreeLearning с той же проблемой и кстати с тем же .sh файлом но мне это не помогло. Я был в https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123790 и здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a- nonzero-exit-code и все эти варианты не подходят, к вашему сведению сам проект основан на Objective-c, хотя не думаю, что это как-то влияет на него, но оставлю это для информации. Убедительно прошу помощи, уже 4 дня не могу запустить проект и перерыл все страницы в интернете. Всем хорошего дня и спасибо за уделенное время.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8035#issuecomment-708896274